# Notification mark shows only if I am inside notification page

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

This code is for navigation bar in my website. When a new notification comes the variable `has_new_notification` will be `true`.

Then the notification-mark should show in `notification` element in the navbar. Also there is a class called `active` that makes the element color in navbar change when I click on the element. The problem: I can only see the `notification-mark` on `notification` element when I am inside notification page.

```html
{% load static %}
<style>
.header__menuItem.active a{ background-color: #51546e; color: #fff; padding: 10px 20px; margin: -10px -20px; border-radius: 10px; } 

.header__menuItem.notification { position: relative; } 

.notification-mark { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: red; border-radius: 50%; }
<style>
     

      <li class="header__menuItem {% if request.path == '/accounts/notofications/' %}active{% endif %} notification">
        <a href="{% url 'notofications' %}">Notifications</a>
        {% if has_new_notification %}
          <span class="notification-mark"></span>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      
      <li class="header__menuItem {% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.path == '/accounts/logout/' %}active{% endif %}"><a href="{% url 'logout' %}" >Logout</a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="header__menuItem {% if request.path == '/accounts/login/' %}active{% endif %}"><a href="{% url 'login' %}" >Login/Sign Up</a></li>

      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I tried removing class: `notification` and only having class: `notification-mark` but then the mark didn't show at all.